# How reliant should I be on Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using session to do two things:

1. Keep track of which css file to load for a particular company.
2. Keep track of the Company Id Guid that tracks what company we are in.

I am seeing that this is coming in as null sometimes but I'm not getting a consistent problem to track down. I have no doubt this is probably something in my code that I need to track down but this bring me up to my questions about session...

1. Am I relying on Session to much to pass information between screens?
2. Is it consistent?
3. What could be clearing it between page loads?
4. Is session easily cleared by the user?
5. Should I be using something else more reliable?

I am worried that I will move this to live usage and have all kinds of problems.

I'm simply doing this:

```
Session["Css"] = css;
```

and reading it the same way:

```
css = Session["Css"]
```

**UPDATE**

The session I am using:

HttpSessionStateBase Controller Session

Comment: What session state mode are you using?

Comment: Sessions do expire after a certain amount of time.  Also, if the app pool recycles or IIS resets, session data is lost if it's stored in process.  If you're using a load balancer, session info can be lost if the load balancer isn't sticky.

Comment: I say go for the cookie -- I can't see an advantage of session and it will be more reliable -- just look at all the websites that use cookies now.

Comment: @Hogan Can't see an advantage to using session over cookie or the other way around?

Comment: @ErocM - "I say go for the cookie" -- I think cookies are better than session variables and thus can't see an advantage to using session variables.  (Even Microsoft's tools use cookies -- read about StateBag in ASP.NET)

Comment: Completely agree with Hogan. ASP.NET Sessions suck like hell and are unreliable. The very first thing I do when I start a new ASP.NET MVC application is to set `<sessionState mode="Off" />` in my web.config to make sure that no developer ever makes the mistake of using sessions.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Good rule of thumb. I think I'll adopt this and move to cookies.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. This has clarified a lot for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few types of Session State. InProc, StateServer, and SqlServer. I believe the default is InProc. You can read more about this on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776818%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

Each of these will obey the timeout value for sessionState defined in your web.config file. For a single server setup (which is what I typically do) I usually have my sessionState setup as follows:

```
<sessionState 
    mode="StateServer" 
    stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
    timeout="2880" />
```

This is the same default timeout as Forms Auth, so my sessions will stick around as long as my users auth cookie/session. This will require you to set the start up on the ASP.NET State Server to `Automatic`. Below is my high-level pass at explaining the types and their potential drawbacks.

### InProc

This will be reset everytime the application pool recycles the worker process for the web app. I believe this is what is happening to you, and this is why your session variables are null at what appear to be random times.

### StateServer

This will persist state across apppool recycles, but requires that you enable the ASP.NET State Server Service, and change it's start up type to Automatic.

You can run into issues if you have a web farm or multiple web servers handling the website, unless you run a dedicated state server.

This requires that variables stored in session variables are `[Serializable]`.

### SQLServer

This will persist session variables to a SQL database, and is is generally the best approach for a web farm situation.

This requires that variables stored in session variables are `[Serializable]`.

Comment: @Nate What are your thoughts about using cookies instead of session?

Comment: My thought is that you should use cookies instead of session.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov :) I know. I just wanted to see his point of view. Two sides of the coin thing.. ya know.

Comment: Um... **write** up actually

Comment: @ErocM I use them as a quick way to store things during a user's session, such as which .css file to render, etc. I generally use cookies when both server code and javascript need them. Main reason, sessions are easy (with a state server or sql server, they persist). I have never had any problems. That said,  others have said they have issues with them, and never use them. Maybe their sites are bigger and used more than mine and stress the session state to its limit, I don't know. I know that I use them. The app I'm working on now uses 3 session variables, so I guess I use them sparingly.

Comment: @Nate thx for the input. I'll do some testing and see how it goes from there. Your info help me greatly though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not be writing your method to GetCss() something along these lines?

```
GetCss() {

    var css = (CastToYourTypeHere)Session["css"];

    if(css == null) {

        //do whatever you'd normally do here to set the css, 
        //e.g. get the users guid and find their company css, and set css equal to it
        css = myHypotheticalGetCssBasedOnTheUserFunction();

    }

    return css;

}
```

That way you're kind of covering all bases in that, you can happily use Session, if it it's lost for whatever reason you're just re-running your initial 'getCssForThisUser' type code.

IMO, session isn't a bad way to hold this kind of data for each user between pages in the type of example you've described.