# how should I store my dynamic css file name within the current session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, razor

I'm not sure how to ask this directly so I'll explain my situation.

We have a portal for our clients and they access the site as such:

http://url.com/webporta/{their guid}/

The guid determines what css file gets loaded for the site:

```
<link href="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/{0}.css", GetCookieInfo.CssFile))" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am reading the css file name and repopulating the cookie EVERY time they visit the site just to make sure I have the current value.

This is where I am reading the database from a service call and writing out the cookie:

```
    var css = client.GetCssFile(id);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(css))
    {
      sb.AppendLine("Setting css to 'Site' default since GetCssFile returned null or empty.");
      css = "Site";
    }
```

and the method that is called to write it:

```
    var httpCookie4 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(CookieEnums.CssFile.ToString());
    return httpCookie4 != null ? httpCookie4.Value : "Site";
```

**This works fine until they visit with a different guid. They only way for it to 'reread' the cookie is to CTRL-F5 to force a refresh of the page.**

There has got to be a better way than this since I cannot seem to get the site to reread the cookies at load time, or at least I don't know how to.

Any suggestions on a better way of handling this?

**========== EDIT #1 ===========**

I tried session originally but had an issue with it timing out. I was also suggested to use cookies on this post:  [How reliant should I be on Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075989/how-reliant-should-i-be-on-session?rq=1)

Comment: Why not store the css file in a session variable?

Comment: If they visit for the first time are you not creating / storing the `Cookie`? if that makes no difference can you store that in ViewState object or Add it to the Current `Session` Session has an `Add` method as well. correct me if I am not understanding your question properly.

Comment: @SystemDown I asked this question here and they suggested using a cookie:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075989/how-reliant-should-i-be-on-session?rq=1

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am creating and storing the cookie EVERY time they goto the site, 'refreshing it'. My problem is when they come back to the site with a new guid, it's not reading the new information that I just put in the cookie for the new guid.

Comment: @ErocM - I personally would lean towards using a session variable which is tamper free.

Comment: @SystemDown Do session variables persist through each page automatically or do you have to pass them?

Comment: The Session Variable is there as long as there is no Session Timeout

Comment: @DJKRAZE that's the part that worries me. I'll have to read up on how to handle that. If it times out, then what? :)

Comment: do you know how to set / adjust Session Timeout? if not do the following `o change session timeout write this code in your web.config file
or you can also set this in global.asax file as
Session.Timeout = 60 ; // in Session.Start() event
it will increase your session expire time .`

Comment: @DJKRAZE you should give that to me as an answer so I can upvote you. I'm going to go with session. Between your posts and the previous question I think I can get the session under control.

Comment: Btw thanks everyone for your answers. You've been a great help.

Comment: @ErocM - If a session times out, then the user is essentially logged out. As previously stated, you can set the timeout period, and it refreshes each time the user does a post back.

Comment: ErocM, I added as an answer per your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ErocM here is something that you can also try

do you know how to set / adjust Session Timeout? if not do the following

`to change session timeout write this code in your web.config file`
`or you can also set this in global.asax file as Session.Timeout = 60;`
`// in Session.Start() event` it will `increase your session expire time` .

Comment: ErocM not a problem glad that we could all lend you some eye opening and useful advise :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the CSS file name in the cookie, have a controller or http handler decide which CSS file to serve based on the GUID.

So the URL would be something like `http://url.com/whatever/GetCSS/{GUID}`. When they visit a site with a different GUID, the response changes to the appropriate CSS file for that GUID.

Comment: That's a thought but our client's already have the url hard coded on their site to go to the logon page directly. Changing it at this point would cause issues.

Comment: You wouldn't have to change the URL of the logon page, you'd just use the GUID from the URL you already have to determine the URL in the `link` tag that's rendered in the response. Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: I am within the logon url that they are going to first. From there I am populating the cookie that the webpages are loading into memory.

Comment: Right, so you'd have something like `<link href="@Url.Action("GetCSS", new {.GUID = GetGUIDFromCurrentURLSomehow})" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`. The GetCSS action would call the code that determines which CSS file to use. You'd use `@Request.Url` to get the GUID from URL, probably.